# Change passed pointer in function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Concerning double indirection (pointer to pointer) and passing those to a function

I cannot change the pointer here in function **void test(int **nmbr, int *n);**

```
int n = 5;
int n2 = 555;   

int *nPtr = &n;
int *n2Ptr = &n2;

printf("the number = %d\n", *nPtr);

test(&nPtr, n2Ptr);

printf("the number is now = %d\n", *nPtr);
```

test

```
void test(int **nPptr, int *n2Ptr) {

 int *p = *nPptr;

 p = n2Ptr;

}
```

since the pointer p points to a copy of *nPtr, right?

But what about this code (this time the pointer points to a given struct in a linkedlist

the code snipped is from the site https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists

```
 int remove_by_index(Person **head, int n) {
int i = 0;
int retval = -1;
Person *current = *head;
Person *temp_node = NULL;

if (n == 0) {
    return pop_first(head);
}

for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    if (current->next == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    current = current->next;
}

temp_node = current->next;
retval = temp_node->nmbr;
current->next = temp_node->next;
free(temp_node);

return retval;

}
```

it removes a given node in the list by a given indexnumber

Here one can see that *current is local copy in the function and traversate in the list and lastly merges two nodes, without problem

So why does it work to change the pointer here but not in the function test(int **nPptr, int *n2Ptr)?

To be clear

in the function **test**:

```
 int *p = *nPptr;
```

p is local copy and copies the pointer from *nPtr

in the function **remove_by_index**

```
Person *current = *head;
```

current is local copy and copies the pointer from *head. The list lives beyond the scope of the function remove_by_index(..) so I do not understand why it can be manipulated in the function by the local pointer *current, at the same time as it does not work to alter nPtr in function test(..)

Comment: In `test`, `p` is a local variable, so changing `p` has no effect outside the function. Changing `*p` would have an effect outside the function, as would changing `*nPptr` or `**nPptr`. For example, your `test` function could do `*nPptr = n2Ptr;` and it would make the external `nPtr` point to `n2`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I know that but what about *current in the other function? - here I can walk between the nodes in the list without problem

Comment: The changes to `current` have no external effect, but the changes to `current->temp` have an external effect.

Comment: Ok, could you post an answer to this question? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a function, changes to pointer variables or pointer parameters have no effect outside the function. However, if the pointer is pointing to an object outside the function, that object can be modified by dereferencing the pointer.

For example, in OP's `test` function:

```
void test(int **nPptr, int *n2Ptr) {
    int *p = *nPptr;

    p = n2Ptr;
}
```

`p` is initialized and then its value is changed by an assignment. This has no effect on any object outside the function. If the function were changed as follows:

```
void test(int **nPptr, int *n2Ptr) {
    int *p = *nPptr;

    p = n2Ptr;

    *nPptr = p;
    *p = 42;
}
```

Then two objects outside the function will have been modified (an `int *` and an `int`).

In OP's `remove_by_index` function, changes to the `current` variable as it progresses through the linked list have no external effect, but the line:

```
current->next = temp_node->next;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(*current).next = (*temp_node).next;
```

The external `Person` object that `current` is pointing to on the linked list has been modified by dereferencing of the pointer and assignment to the `next` member of the `Person` it is pointing to.